# KVM switch with VNC server

Tags: vnc, keyboard-video-mouse

Does anyone know of a KVM switch that is also a VNC (or other protocol like it) server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've always used Avocent and really like the built in web console:

http://www.avocent.com/Products/Category/KVM_Appliances/IP_Appliances/AutoView_Digital_KVM_Appliances.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I used a 16 port Startech IP KVM that supported the VNC protocol. I could VNC into the IP of the device and switch to the desired machine. It was a little clunky, but that could be because it was over a T1 that I was connecting. Connecting locally was acceptable, but that's about all you need to issue a ctrl-alt-del on a hung machine anyhow. I will try to find the exact device I used.

[HERE](http://www.startech.com/item/SV1641HDIE-16-port-Enhanced-Digital-KVM-Switch-over-IP.aspx) is the link.

Comment: "Product ID does not exist."

Comment: Not sure whats happening for you, as the link works for me. Anyhow, its a Startech 16 port KVM, SV1641HDIE

Comment: We have also used various StarTech KVMs and been fairly happy with them.  We've had the SV1110IPEXT and SV1115IPEXT, which are "1 port" units which we then connect to their 16-port cascadable units for over 130 ports.  They now have a consolidated unit that has the 16 ports and the VNC unit built together, for around $1K.  The downside: it is picky about VNC versions, we have to use a specific version.  Also, their support is not good, they don't really make them they just resell them.  When a power brick went, their answer was "you're on your own".  We ended up releasing the magic smoke...

Answer (score 3):

I have used Adder IPEPS, it works well enough.  One uses VNC to connect to it.  One has to sync the mouse quite often, I would give it 3.5 out 5 stars.  Also it is quite expensive ($600???).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your configuration, you might be able to cobble together something using VNC in conjunction with [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/), if the two machines are near each other. If you have Linux as your primary Synergy system I use QuickSynergy as the GUI to simplify things on my setup.

Comment: This doesn't do anything KVM switchy. It just does what VNC or Microsoft Remote Desktop already do.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search brought me to a page that listed a bunch of IP based KVM switches, which is what I believe you are looking for. I have not used them as they are pricey for my current needs, and back when I really needed them, they did not exist.

http://www.kvm-switches-online.com/kvm-switch-over-ip.html

Answer (score 1):

You could get one of these http://www.lantronix.com/it-management/kvm-over-ip/ and plug it into any KVM

One gatcha : your KVM will have to allow keyboard macros to allow you to change to diffrent KVM ports (it wouldnt work if you have to push a physical button on the KVM to flip to diffrent machines)